# How to setup AGI in Freepbx using nodejs

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, asterisk, freepbx

How can I setup AGI in FreePBX asterisk system for outbound calls. I am using twilio trunks for making outbound calls.

I am actually integrating dialogflow with FreePBX using Nodejs service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

There are no difference between asterisk with Freepbx and without Freepbx.

You should do two thing

1) create AGI script and put it in /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin

2) Insert AGI command into dialplan.

Only really complex thing here - Freepbx developers never know you want use it for your need, so you have use freepbx module hooks or dialplan hooks for add your AGI. Which is impossible without deep experience with Freepbx and freepbx modules.

I think you should start with module howto on freepbx site.

Comment: Thank you for your response, will try module